# Handling files in Django

Tags: django, django-models, imagemagick, magickwand, wand

I'm using ImageMagick and [the binding wand](http://dahlia.kr/wand/wand/image.html) to generate thumbnails for uploaded images in Django.  I can generate the thumbnail fine, but I'm uncertain about how to go about passing the image object from ImageMagick back into the Django model.  So I have a simplified model as below:

```
from wand import Image

class Attachment(models.Model):
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to="some_path")
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="other_path")

    def generate_thumb(self):
        with Image(file=self.attachment) as wand:
            thumb = wand.resize(width=50, height=50)
            thumb.save(file=self.thumbnail)
```

This generates an error at the last line of `ValueError: The 'thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it.`  Is there a simple way to get a file object out of wand and into django without too much silliness?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you use the 'generate_thumb' function? There is probably another place in your code with a reference to it.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer**: I am the creator of [Wand](http://dahlia.github.com/wand/) you are trying to use.

First of all, `ImageField` requires PIL.  It means you don’t need Wand, because you probably already installed an another image library.  However I’ll answer to your question without any big changes.

It seems that `self.thumbnail` was not initialized yet at the moment, so you have to create a new [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/files/file/#the-file-class) or [`ImageFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/files/file/#the-imagefile-class) first:

```
import io

def generate_thumb(self):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with Image(file=self.attachment) as wand:
        wand.resize(width=50, height=50)
        wand.save(file=buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)
    self.thumbnail = ImageFile(buffer)
```

Plus, `from wand import Image` will raise `ImportError`.  It should be changed:

```
from wand.image import Image
```

Comment: Thank you for this; although I was fighting with using the PIL version of ImageFile. As most would know, I should have been usingthe django wrapper: from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is easy thumbnails in your django app try: https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail

Its pretty popular and active.